# Structure.ByValue object not working properly when used as a structure field

Tags: java, jna

Consider I have the following C struct definitions:

```
struct StructB {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct StructA {
    struct StructB *ref;
    struct StructB value;
};
```

which are represented in Java by:

```
public class StructA extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference {
    public StructB.Reference ref;
    public StructB value;

    public StructA() {
        ref = new StructB.Reference();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"ref", "value"});
    }
}

public class StructB extends Structure {
    public static class Reference extends StructB implements Structure.ByReference { }
    public int a;
    public int b;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b"});
    }
}
```

If a allocate a new `StructA` object in Java and set its fields with:

```
StructA sa = new StructA();
sa.ref.a = 1;
sa.ref.b = 2;
sa.value.a = 3;
sa.value.b = 4;
```

and pass `sa` to the C function:

```
void printnest(struct StructA *s) {
    printf("Printing structA...\n");
    printf("\ts->ref->a: %d\n", s->ref->a);
    printf("\ts->ref->b: %d\n", s->ref->b);
    printf("\ts->value.a: %d\n", s->value.a);
    printf("\ts->value.b: %d\n", s->value.b);
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Printing structA...
    s->ref->a: 1
    s->ref->b: 2
    s->value.a: 3
    s->value.b: 4
```

which is correct.

However, if I declare another static class inside `StructB` like this:

```
public class StructB extends Structure {
    public static class Reference extends StructB implements Structure.ByReference { }
    public static class Value extends StructB implements Structure.ByValue { }
    public int a;
    public int b;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b"});
    }
}
```

and declare the `value` field of `StructA` to explicitly be a `Structure.ByValue` with this:

```
public class StructA extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference {
    public StructB.Reference ref;
    public StructB.Value value;

    public StructA() {
        ref = new StructB.Reference();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"ref", "value"});
    }
}
```

I get the following output calling `printnest` passing `sa` again:

```
Printing structA...
    s->ref->a: 1
    s->ref->b: 2
    s->value.a: 0
    s->value.b: 0
```

So, the fields of the `StructB.Value` field of `StructA` are not correct. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Structure.ByValue`.  JNA assumes by-value semantics to begin with for structure-typed fields; the `Structure.ByValue` tag actually triggers special handling which assumes (perhaps over-broadly) that it is dealing with a by-value function parameter or return value.

Feel free to [file an issue](https://github.com/twall/jna/issues).

Comment: I've heard that if a `Structure` subclass doesn't implement neither `ByValue` nor `ByReference`, so, implicitly, it behaves like `ByValue` if it is a field of another `Structure` and like `ByReference` if it is passed to a function. However, I thought telling a `Structure` field of a `Structure`'s subclass object to be, explicitly, `ByValue` wouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: By default, `Structure` is treated as `struct*` when used as an argument or return value, and as `struct` when used as a structure field.  You *only* need to explicitly specify `ByValue` or `ByReference` if you want behavior different than the default.  In the case of `ByValue` fields, JNA mistakenly treats the field as it does `ByValue` arguments, i.e. enforcing separate memory allocation, which is appropriate for an argument, but not a field.